# Why is this only printing one letter every time I try?

Tags: python

```
from random import choice
print ("Enigma") 

list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
range (0,25) 

cha2 = choice(list)



complete = choice(list) 

for x in range (0, 90000):
    ("Type alphabet") 
    cha1=input() 
    print (complete)
```

When I run it and input an alphabet the same alphabet outputs as the first time. However I want it to output a different random alphabet each time I enter an alphabet. Thanks

Comment: Where do you ask to *repick* a value. `choice(some_list)` does *not* returns a random generator, it simply returns a *random* element. So from then on, `complete` and `cha2` are fixed.

Comment: What exactly is your code suppose to be doing?

Comment: I think `complete = choice(list)` should be *inside* the loop, but it's not really clear

Comment: Consider using [`string.ascii_uppercase`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) and not naming a variable `list`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem How do I solve this to make a random letter generator that doesn't print the inputted letter?

Answer (score 0):

Chris_Rands has it right in the comments...

`complete = choice(list)` is the line that choose a letter to return, and you are only running it one time.  If you wanted it to run every time, you need to put it inside your `while` loop:

```
from random import choice
print ("Enigma") 

list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

for x in range (0, 90000):
    ("Type alphabet") 
    cha1=input() 
    complete = choice(list) # This is the key change here
    print (complete)
```

Comment: But what is the need of input() here?

Answer (score 0):

To answer: "I want it to output a different random alphabet each time I enter an alphabet"

From the above, you will check cha1 against the complete, and while they are the same, keep calling choice to update

```
cha1=input() 
complete = choice(list)
while cha1 == complete:
    complete = choice(list)
```